# JS Function Invocation from AS3 with Complex Object in Parameter

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, apache-flex, air, jwplayer

I'm building an AIR desktop application.  At one point the application loads a popup window (an MXML component based on [s:Window](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/Window.html)), which contains an [mx:HTML](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/HTML.html) component which loads a local (in the application directory) html file, *blank.html*.  The relevant elements in *blank.html* are:

```
<script src="jw/jwplayer.js"/> <!--JW Player's JS-based Embedder-->
...
<div id="jwtarget" /> <!-- the target that the embedder will use -->
```

Since the parameters I want to use are determined at runtime, I use the `domWindow` property to invoke the method which loads the player.  Here's an example that works:

```
private function injectPlayer():void {
  var playerVars:Object = {};
  playerVars.flashplayer = "jw/player.swf";
  playerVars.file = "http://www.archive.org/download/meet_john_doe_ipod/meet_john_doe_512kb.mp4";
  playerVars.height = 360;
  playerVars.width = 640;

  try { // attempt to invoke the js function
    htmlComponent.domWindow.jwplayer("jwtarget").setup(playerVars);
  } catch(e:Error) {}

}
```

which is called when the page finishes loading by:

```
<mx:HTML id="htmlComponent" location="assets/blank.html" complete="injectPlayer()" />
```

That all works fine.

Now to the question.  I need to be able to pass a more complex `playerVars` Object to the function, but I don't seem to be getting the syntax correct.  Here's the simplest example I've been attempting:

```
private function injectPlayer():void {
  var playerVars:Object = {};
  //playerVars.flashplayer = "jw/player.swf";
  playerVars.file = "http://www.archive.org/download/meet_john_doe_ipod/meet_john_doe_512kb.mp4";
  playerVars.height = 360;
  playerVars.width = 640;
  playerVars.modes = [{"type":"flash","src":"jw/player.swf"}];

  try { // attempt to invoke the js function
    htmlComponent.domWindow.jwplayer("jwtarget").setup(playerVars);
  } catch(e:Error) {}

}
```

This code should create the exact same thing as the above code, but it fails to execute.  I assume I need to change the syntax in some way to allow the array of Objects (`modes`) to be passed properly as a parameter to the js function.

I've tried various things, like passing the `modes` as a String, or putting the whole thing through `JSON.stringify()` first, but to no avail.  Anyone know the correct way for constructing a complex object for a parameter?

Other details, if you haven't inferred them by now: Flex 4.5.1 is the SDK I'm building with, including the AIR 3.0 extensions (which means targeting FP11).

**Update:**

Another configuration I tried, which does work:

```
playerVars.modes = {"type":"flash", "src":"jw/player.swf"};
```

However, this still doesn't solve the problem that I should be able to pass an Array of Objects in the `modes` property.  But at least this way loads the video player.

**More Update:**

So, I found this little section of code from *jwplayer.js* where I suspected the player loading was failing:

```
if (typeof parsedConfig.modes == "string") {
  _modes = _playerDefaults();
  _modes[0].src = parsedConfig.modes;
} else if (parsedConfig.modes instanceof Array) {  // I suspect this was eval'd as false
  _modes = parsedConfig.modes;
} else if (typeof parsedConfig.modes == "object" && parsedConfig.modes.type) {
  _modes = [parsedConfig.modes];
}
```

And to test my suspicion I added the following function to my *blank.html*:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var instanceOfArrayTest = function(arr) {
    return arr instanceof Array;
  }
</script>
```

And in my ActionScript code tried the following:

```
trace([1,2,3] is Array); // true
trace(htmlComponent.domWindow.instanceOfArrayTest([1,2,3])); // false!!!!
```

So, it seems that the problem is that ActionScript is not passing AS3 Array objects as JS Array objects!

Comment: playerVars.modes = [{"type":"flash"}]; Is this supposed to be an array with the first element an object?

Comment: @The_asMan - Yes.  Normally one would include other possible modes, also as objects, eg. `[{"type":"flash", "src":"player.swf"},{"type":"html5"},{"type":"download"}]`, which defines an order series of possible fallbacks.  Hopefully, the fact that I forgot the '"src": "player.swf"' when initially posted the question didn't throw you off.  I amended it as soon as I noticed.

Comment: Just seems odd to me that the parameter would be an array of objects but the objects only have one attribute. This all could be done on one object or an associative array. I am willing to bet its not set up correctly

Comment: @The_asMan - If you have a look at the [JW Embedder Modes documentation](http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/jw-player-for-flash-v5/18508/jw-embedder-modes) on LongtailVideo, the API will make more sense.  For example, one can also specify alternative files to be played per type object. Stuff like that comes in handy when, say, you want to offer HTML5 video that is valid for Chrome/IE (h264) and Firefox (ogg).  The example in my question was supposed to be just enough to cause the video player not to load (when it should be ;), and certainly not much of a real world example.

Comment: Did you try playerVars.modes = [{"type":"flash","src":"player.swf"}]; if the player is in the same directory as jwplayer.js when jwplayer.js runs the function it will be relative to that file.

Comment: @The_asMan - Yes, that was one of the first things I made sure to check.  No, all the paths need to be relative to the html file, not to the _jwplayer.js_.  To verify, I tried using just `"player.swf"` in both the initial working example, and in the update that I just added.  Both fail, unless the `jw` directory is specified.  Thanks for the suggestion anyway.

Comment: Yeah, I don't know anymore. Have you just tried to write a blank html page with that code and verify that the code itself works? Its been about 2 years since I played with JWplayer. Another thing in the docs height and width are are strings on the link you provided. Also try adding 'id': 'playerID' just because thats what they show in the docs.

Comment: Another thing modes is plural and you only assigned 1 mode "flash" try adding another mode below it { type: "html5" } The jwplayer does little validation.

Comment: found your issue you need to set provider. as per the docs "Is the provider option set? If yes, use Flash. If no, move to 3." http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/jw-player-for-flash-v5/18508/jw-embedder-modes so try and add 'provider': 'video'

Comment: @The_asMan - No, that's not it.  Otherwise the updated example I gave wouldn't be working.  It's something with the serializing/parsing of the Array literal when it's passed.  I also haven't ruled out the possibility of some silent Sandbox exception that might be triggered by using an Array, but that's a wild guess.

Comment: But your updated example is not including the provider. Which as the docs say will cause it to skip the flash mode and move to the next mode. In your case there is no next mode.

Comment: @The_asMan - You're reading the docs incorrectly.  "Moving to 3" means it then checks whether the extension (in this case mp4) is supported (which it is).  Not including the provider does not cause flash to be rejected.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4372/discussion-between-merv-and-the-asman)

Comment: But why even let it get to 3 just provide the provider which in your case is "http" not "video" like I said before.

Comment: If I could make a suggestion. Assuming you are trying to support html5 for ipad and mobiles( the reason you want to use modes ). I suggest you drop JWplayer and use flowplayer. It is much much easier to use. check it out http://flowplayer.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike the [call()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html#call%28%29) method of the [ExternalInterface](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html) class, the mx:HTML does not automatically convert AS3 classes to corresponding JS classes when they are passed as parameters to a JS function.  Instead, the [HTML Control](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/HTML.html) maintains an environment where methods and properties native to the AS3 classes are preserved and made accessible to JS directly.

If a JS function requires a JS Array object, one must create the JS Array explicitly using the JavaScript `Window` object to access the JS `Array` constructor.  The HTML Control provides access to this with it's [domWindow](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/HTML.html#domWindow) property.  Otherwise, there is no way to "cast" an AS3 Array to a JS Array.

Here's a basic example:

```
var JSArray:Function = htmlComponent.domWindow.Array;
htmlComponent.domWindow.instanceOfArrayTest( JSArray(1,2,3) ); // true
```

And for the more complex example using the config parameter for JW Player:

```
playerVars.modes = JSArray({"type":"flash","src":"jw/player.swf"},{"type":"html5"});
```

which creates a JS Array of two Objects.

For more info on the JavaScript environment in the HTML Control, check out the [JavaScript in AIR](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=AboutHTMLEnvironment_4.html#1042224) section of Adobe's *Developing AIR Applications with Flex*.

Answer (score 2):

Try doing this instead:

```
playerVars.modes = [{type:"flash",src:"jw/player.swf"}];
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @J_A_X.  This didn't resolve the problem, but from my tests it is just as valid as the initial form that I put it in.  That is, both this syntax and the one I used _appear_ to have been parsed correctly in the object that the JS function returns.  I'm beginning to think that perhaps the root of the problem might be different. :(